# JavaFX PulseLogger - How to find which nodes are NOT cached?

Tags: javafx, rendering, gluon-mobile, javafxports, pulse

I am experiencing some laggy-ness in my JavaFX Application when scrolling, and whenever the scene needs re-rendering. Enabling the pulselogger in JavaFX I can see that a number of nodes are rerendered in each pulse (as in the example below).

```
PULSE: 3310 [16ms:26ms] 
T1 (0 +0ms): CSS Pass 
T1 (0 +0ms): Layout Pass 
T1 (0 +0ms): Update bounds
T1 (0 +13ms): Waiting for previous rendering 
T1 (13 +0ms): Copy state to render graph 
T7 (14 +0ms): Dirty Opts Computed 
T7 : 1 different dirty regions to render 
T7 : Dirty Region 0: RectBounds { minX:366.0, minY:143.0, maxX:374.0, maxY:539.0} (w:8.0, h:396.0) 
T7 : Render Root Path 0: [com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion@bd6cd80, com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion@b6f5240, com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion@1347d5a0, com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion@b982360, com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion@b9826c0] 
T7 (14 +0ms): Render Roots Discovered 
T7 (14 +1ms): Painting 
T7 (16 +10ms): Presenting 
Counters:
        CacheFilter rebuilding: 1
        Nodes cached: 8
        Nodes rendered: 19
        Nodes visited during render: 25
```

**Is there an easy way to find those 19 nodes re-rendered so that I can cache them to improve performance?**

Comment: You mean dynamically or by hand?

Comment: @user1803551 I don’t get the question. In any easy way

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no easy way. The whole pulse information message is internal API. The increment to the "Nodes rendered" counter is done from `NGNode` (the peer of the public `Node`) in its `doRender` method if the node needs to be rendered. The `PulseLogger` and `PrintLogger` classes handle the logging and printing of the information.

You would have to modify these classes so that `NGNode` does not just increment the counter, but sends its own information (like id or name); or intercept the method calls somehow.

An alternative is to [submit a request](https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/) and it might be available in a future version.